# how to add a stop button to downloader

Tags: c#

I'm working on a downloader manger to my app but I couldn't know how to make the Stop button work I search for solution but I couldn't find anything can help me
The code is 
[c#]

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnDownload.Enabled = false;
  btnStop.Enabled = true;
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
  webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url.Text), path.Text ; )
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}

private void btnstop (object sender , e)
{
  btnDownload.Enabled = true;
  btnstop.Enabled = false;
  progressbar.value = 0;   
}
```

Comment: maybe `webclient.CancelAsync()`? - `when you call CancelAsync to cancel a DownloadStringAsync operation, if you have specified an event handler for the DownloadStringCompleted event, your event handler receives notification that the operation has ended.` [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Nitro.de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932626) says, you should use [WebClient.CancelAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Cancels a pending asynchronous operation.

and remember checking if the `e.Cancelled` is true

```
private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)
        MessageBox.Show("Download cancelled!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a WebClient async request, you can call the `WebClient.CancelAsync` method as found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that this still calls the download completed handler, so you will have to check if `e.Canceled` is **true** in your `Completed` function before showing the message box.

Comment: Can you write it to me cuz I don't know how to do it :/